# Using require.js packages to manage large applications

Tags: javascript, architecture, package, requirejs

We would like to create an app layout that consists of one main module that requires packages. Each package (including the main module) has its own dependencies to third party libraries and other local packages. Therefore in each package's main.js, we have a require.config section like the following:

```
require.config({
  packages: ["package2"],
  context: 'package1',
  shim: {
    'underscore': {
      exports: '_'
    }
  },

  paths: {
    underscore: '../lib/underscore-1.4.3'  
  }
});
```

As you can see the config defines paths and packages. The top level main.js looks like this:

```
require.config({
  packages: ["package1"]
});
```

The project has a directory structure like so...

```
├── package1
│   ├── package1.jade
│   ├── package1.js
│   └── main.js
├── lib
│   ├── backbone-0.9.10.js
│   └── underscore-1.4.3.js
├── package2
│   ├── package2.js
│   ├── main.js
└── main.js
```

The goal is we can have sets of "packages" that packages and pages can depend on not just modules.  In a perfect work the dependency graph of the project would look something like this:

```
   +------------+           +-------------+
   |  package1  +--+     +--+  package2   +--+
   +------------+  |     |  +-------------+  |
                   |     |                   |
                   v     v                   v
                +--------------+       +--------------+
                |  package3    |       |  package4    |
                +----------+---+       +--------------+
                           |
                           |             +-------------+
                           +------------>|   common    |
                                         +-------------+
```

And inside of each package as well we would have a project structure.  Creating a modular architecture for our JS.  Is this style possible with require.js and it's packages, or are we thinking about packages wrong?  If so is there a js dependency managment library that will help us accomplish this architecture?

we threw together a sample structure on github, https://github.com/austinbv/require_js_package_sample

lastly we have asked the same on the require mailing list *https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/requirejs/bNj4mXNWq-8* but have not seen much intrest so we came here.  If the list updates I will be sure to update my question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what packages are for in RequireJS except for supporting code that is already built in `CommonJS Package` format. Is it possible for you to switch on modules to provide the same component-based structure?

I use modules to provide such structure. Each module is defined in `AMD.js` as following:

```js
define(
  [
    // Paths and shims defined in configuration of RequireJS application.
    'utils', 
    'jQuery',
    'underscore',
    // Component's view and behaviour if any.
    'text!./main.html',
    'text!./main.js',
    // Other dependencies.
    'Components/Commons/Component/AMD.js',  // Component Class.
    'Components/Views/ProductsTile/AMD.js', // Required component.
    ...
  ],
  function (...) {
    ...
    return new Component(args);
  }
);
```

Simplified project's structure is the following:

```
SimplifiedProject
├── Assets
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── main.css
│  ... ...
│   └── img
│       └── noImage.jpg
├── Components
│   ├── Application.js
│   ├── Commons
|   |  ...
│   │   └── Utils
│   │       └── AMD.js
│   ├── Libs
│   │   ├── jQuery
│   │   │   └── jquery.min.js
│   │   ├── RequireJS
│   │   │   ├── plugins
│   │   │   │   ├── json.js
│   │   │   │   └── text.js
│   │  ...  └── require.js
│   ├── Models
│   │   └── Product
│   │       ├── AMD.js
│   │       └── Model.js
│   ├── Controllers
|   |   ...
│   └── Views
│       ├── Main
│       │   ├── AMD.js
│       │   ├── main.css
│       │   ├── main.html
│       │   └── main.js
│      ...
│       └── ProductsTile
│           ├── AMD.js
│           ├── main.css
│           ├── main.html
│           └── main.js
├── favicon.ico
└── index.html
```

You can find the whole unfinished project [here](https://github.com/ipetrovilya/discussions_with_ipetrovilya/tree/master/RequireJsModularProject).

It is three months since you posted your question and I'm eager to know how you have resolved it. Please, let me know.